# redirect is not saving value in localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-hooks

that is my all code, a simple page, the user put his name in input and click on the button to be redirect, but how the function is executed before than the setItem the value is not going to localstorage

```
    function Singup() {

    const history = useHistory();

    const [username, setUsername] = useState('')

    function NameValue(event) {
        event.preventDefault()

        const formData = new FormData(event.target);
        const data = Object.fromEntries(formData);

        setUsername(data.name)

        history.push('/MainScreen')
    }

    localStorage.setItem('DataUser', username)

    return (
        <main className="all">
            <div className="bloco">
                <h2>Welcome to CoadLeap network!</h2>
                <p>Please enter your username</p>
                <form className="formulario" onSubmit={NameValue}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <div className="field">
                            <h2>What's in your mind?</h2>
                            <input
                                placeholder="Insira um nome aqui!"
                                type="text"
                                name="name"
                                className="form-input"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <button
                            type="submit"
                            className="singup-btn"
                        >Singup</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </main>
    )
}
```

Comment: By _is not going to localStorage_ do you mean there is no item named `DataUser` at all, or you get `DataUser`: undefined/null/empty ?

Answer (score 0):

Call `setItem` right after the user submits the form:

```
 function NameValue(event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    const formData = new FormData(event.target);
    const data = Object.fromEntries(formData);

    setUsername(data.name)
    localStorage.setItem('DataUser', data.name)
    history.push('/MainScreen')
}
```

Comment: it worked, thanks, the problem is the setUsername, i just was calling the localstorage outside because it was not working inside with usestate

Comment: updating state is `async`, so when you called `setItem` right after `setUsername`, it was invoked before `username` was actually updated.

Answer (score 0):

you could try putting it directly before doing the push:

```
function Singup() {

    const history = useHistory();

    const [username, setUsername] = useState('')

    function NameValue(event) {
        event.preventDefault()

        const formData = new FormData(event.target);
        const data = Object.fromEntries(formData);

        setUsername(data.name)
        
        localStorage.setItem('DataUser', data.name)


        history.push('/MainScreen')
    }

    
    return (
        <main className="all">
            <div className="bloco">
                <h2>Welcome to CoadLeap network!</h2>
                <p>Please enter your username</p>
                <form className="formulario" onSubmit={NameValue}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <div className="field">
                            <h2>What's in your mind?</h2>
                            <input
                                placeholder="Insira um nome aqui!"
                                type="text"
                                name="name"
                                className="form-input"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <button
                            type="submit"
                            className="singup-btn"
                        >Singup</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </main>
    )
}
```